# How to create indexes in MongoDB via .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

I've programmatically created a new document collection using the MongoDB C# driver.

At this point I want to create and build indexes programmatically. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating MongoDB Unique Key with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218966/creating-mongodb-unique-key-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Starting from v2.0 of the driver there's a new `async`-only API. The old API should no longer be used as it's a blocking facade over the new API and is deprecated.

The currently recommended way to create an index is by calling and awaiting `CreateOneAsync` with an `IndexKeysDefinition` you get by using `Builders.IndexKeys`:

```
static async Task CreateIndexAsync()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("HamsterSchool");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Hamster>("Hamsters");
    var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(hamster => hamster.Name);
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new CreateIndexModel<Hamster>(indexKeysDefinition));
}
```

Comment: Quick question for the peanut gallery I am a big fan of the strongly typed lambdas in C# over magic strings elsewhere but the question becomes assume the Hamster object had an array of addresses (billing, physical, mailing, etc) and I also wanted to index by zip code.  Unfortunately once you hit Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Addresses.First().ZipCode) the index creates as if zip code was on the root class hamster.  The documentation on docs.mongodb.com is sparse at best.

Comment: So you should create index only once at application startup?

Comment: @DavideQuaglio That's what I usually do. It's enough to only do it just once, but this guarantees idempotency.

Comment: Please also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248295/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-create-index

Answer (score 46):

you should use `CreateIndex` as `EnsureIndex` is marked obsolete for future compatibility with the next versions of `MongoDB`:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("db");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Hamster>("Hamsters");

collection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<Hamster>.Ascending(_ => _.Name));
```

Comment: @PhilBarresi Do you mean drop the existing one and build a new one? Or simply build another index?
Both do not happen.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong; it sends the command to build an index, but if the index is already built it will result in a no-op; my misunderstanding came from an error with a foreground index creation causing other createindex calls to become blocked, leading me to believe that they were rebuilding the index. Apologies all, I3arnon is right here.

Comment: CreateIndex seems to be marked obsolete in my code whereas EnsureIndex is not. Is this info definitely correct? It seems unlikely to me that they'd have switched which ones were obsoleted in a version update (so I can't believe its just that we are looking at different versions of the code).

Comment: @Chris I don't know what version are you using, but in the latest stable one `EnsureIndex` is obsolete. It's the same in the current version of the [source code on github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollection.cs#L406)

Comment: @I3arnon: I'm on an older version, 1.8.3 from nuget, it seems. Still weird that they went from createIndex being obsolete in the version I have with EnsureIndex being recommended to the other way round. Thanks for taking the time to check, and indeed for pointing me at the github source. Very useful.

Comment: For what its worth this change seems to have been made in 1.9.0 - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Release%20Notes/Change%20Log%20v1.9.0-Driver.txt

Comment: I am using `collectionName.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<TDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(doc => doc.Field));` with v2.2.4.

Answer (score 41):

The overload of `CreateOneAsync` in the currently accepted answer is now marked as obsolete with the message "Use CreateOneAsync with a CreateIndexModel instead." Here's how you do it:

```
static async Task CreateIndex(string connectionString)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase("HamsterSchool");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Hamster>("Hamsters");
    var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions();
    var indexKeys = Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(hamster => hamster.Name);
    var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<Hamster>(indexKeys, indexOptions);
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Something like this should do:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost");
var db = server.GetDatabase("myapp");

var users = db.GetCollection<User>("users");

users.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("EmailAddress"));
```

Please see the following bits in the documentation:

- http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/06bcd201-8844-3df5-d170-15f2b423675c.htm

Comment: Obsolete, see I3arnon answer

Answer (score 5):

There is an entire area on Indexing under the Definitions and Builders documentation page:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/definitions/#index-keys

Example:

```
IndexKeysDefinition<MyModel> keys = "{ Reference: 1 }";
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MyModel>(keys);
await _context.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
```

Comment: It is worth nothing this references an older driver version. It has changed since. At the time of writing 2.13 is the most recent: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/driver/definitions/#index-keys

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to create indexes in c# is by using the driver wrapper library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities). here's an example of creating a text index:

```cs
    DB.Index<Author>()
      .Key(a => a.Name, Type.Text)
      .Key(a => a.Surname, Type.Text)
      .Create();
```

and to do a full-text search, you simply do:

```cs
    DB.SearchText<Author>("search term");
```

haven't seen anything else that makes it simpler than that.