# Exception while closing MongoGridFSStream

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I use the function Close of the class MongoGridFSStream. But, an exception was caught:

```
Command 'filemd5' failed: need an index on { files_id : 1 , n : 1 } (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "need an index on { files_id : 1 , n : 1 }" })
```

Does anybody have any suggestion to resolve this problem?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try creating an index?

Comment: How can create index with the mongodb c# driver?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22452925/885318