# MongoDB C# Driver Create Index

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I just updated my MongoDB from version 2.5.0 to 2.7.0. Visual Studio tells me that the following way to create an index is obsolete:

```cs
protected override Task OnPerformMaintenanceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    => NotificationLogs.Indexes
                       .CreateOneAsync(Builders<NotificationLog>.IndexKeys
                                                                .Ascending(_ => _.TimestampUtc));
```

It suggests me to use [CreateIndexModel](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_CreateIndexModel_1.htm).

The only problem is that I cannot find an example to get this working that will do the same.

I tried:

```
protected Task OnPerformMaintenanceTestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Old approach
  var builder = Builders<NotificationLog>.IndexKeys
                                         .Ascending(x => x.TimestampUtc);

  // New approach
  var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<NotificationLog>(nameof(NotificationLog.TimestampUtc));
  
  return NotificationLogs.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
}
```

But I get the following exception:

`System.FormatException: 'JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'TimestampUtc'.'`

Comment: Just a side note: "Obsolete" is usually an attribute provided by the author of a function. So it isn't ReSharper that is telling you this, but the IDE itself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The new way in the MongoDB 2.7 driver is to do the following:

```
var notificationLogBuilder = Builders<NotificationLog>.IndexKeys;
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<NotificationLog>(notificationLogBuilder.Ascending(x => x.TimestampUtc));

// .NET Full framwork:
// .NET Standard library:
await IMongoCollection.Indexes
                      .CreateOneAsync(indexModel, cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
                      .ConfigureAwait(false);

// .NET Core:
await IMongoCollection.Indexes
                      .CreateOneAsync(indexModel, cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it throws Mongodbtimeout exceptions for me. Any idea if am missing anything?

Comment: What's your `max connection idle time`? Sounds like you need to increse that time. That has nothing to do with this query.

Comment: it is 30000ms that Mongodb has by default for connection timeouts

Answer (score 6):

There is a not type safe method for a BsonDocument with the index options here:

```cs
var indexBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys;
var keys = indexBuilder.Ascending("timestamp");
var options = new CreateIndexOptions
{
    Name = "expireAfterSecondsIndex",
    ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.MaxValue
};
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<BsonDocument>(keys, options);

// .NET full framework
// .NET Standard library:
await collection.Indexes
                .CreateOneAsync(indexModel, cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

// .NET Core
await collection.Indexes
                .CreateOneAsync(indexModel, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: you mean not type safe?

Answer (score -3):

The following is working for me.

```
public async Task CreateIndexOnCollection(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, string field)
{
    var keys = Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(field);
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys);
}
```

or if we know what our indexes will be beforehand, we can use strongly typed implementation like this:

```
public async Task CreateIndexOnNameField()
{
    var keys = Builders<User>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Name);
    await _usersCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys);
}
```

Comment: This is the obsolete way

Comment: @StuiterSlurf True, do you know how to use is with `CreateIndexModel` ?

Comment: @mardok Do you mean the awnser above this?