# MongoDB collection design to link records

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a "Name" collection and when I am doing the POST call, I would search the database if there are any records which matches with SSN and will create a record with same name_id, basically to link the records with same SSN.

Also at the same time, I would be creating the NameDetails for every record.

The purpose of it is, when I do a GET call by SSN, it should fetch all records with matching SSN from Name collection and its respective NameDetails.

Currently, the Database design looks like below where name_id is a incremental sequence. But I do not want to use this as its a traditional way of doing in SQL.

I want to improve this without much impact on performance and also the code for create and fetch data from database.

Name Collection:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c136d35bf3d5c59bda4"), "name_id" : 1, "name" : "John", "ssn" : "111-22-3333" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c136d35bf3d5c59bda5"), "name_id" : 1, "name" : "Fred", "ssn" : "111-22-3333" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c136d35bf3d5c59bda6"), "name_id" : 1, "name" : "Smith", "ssn" : "111-22-3333" }

NameDetails collection:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c18b05c551ab88d28c7"), "name_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c136d35bf3d5c59bda4"), "name_details" : { "Case1" }}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c18b05c551ab88d28c8"), "name_id" : ObjectId("5eda8c136d35bf3d5c59bda5"), "name_details" : { "Case2" }}

Answer (score 0):

You cant do something much different from

`var linkedElements = await dbcollection.FindAsync(item => item.name_id == myNameId)`

Just create proper indexes to optimize queries of this type.

You can create a normal ascending index, you can do this manually on db, or automatically with c# code.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807577/how-to-create-indexes-in-mongodb-via-net).